# Problems creating a custom report with gridview and several textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Good morning, I´m trying to create a custom gridview export system but i cant get all 5 textboxes inside de reports. i really dont know how to perform a caption to make it possible... so, i really need help :).

i have 5 textboxes: title, subtitle, info1, info2, info3, we need to export that input with all the gridview information.

This is my code for the moment:

Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" PageSize="3">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="S" HeaderText="S" SortExpression="S" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="D" HeaderText="D" SortExpression="D" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="I" HeaderText="I" SortExpression="I" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="G" HeaderText="G" SortExpression="G" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="R" SortExpression="R" HeaderImageUrl="http://localhost:41164/images/1.png" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Adherencia" SortExpression="Adherencia" HeaderImageUrl="http://localhost:41164/images/2.png" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="R2" SortExpression="R2" ReadOnly="True" HeaderImageUrl="http://localhost:41164/images/3.png" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="P" HeaderText="P" SortExpression="P" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0000ff" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Word Export:

```
        protected void btnExportWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
        "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.doc");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word ";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

Excel Export:

```
                protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
         "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
            //Apply text style to each Row
            row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
        }
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

        //style to format numbers to string
        string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

Pdf Export:

```
        protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
         "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Csv Export:

```
        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
         "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.csv");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/text";

        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            //add separator
            sb.Append(GridView1.Columns[k].HeaderText + ',');
        }
        //append new line
        sb.Append("\r\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                //add separator
                sb.Append(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k].Text + ',');
            }
            //append new line
            sb.Append("\r\n");
        }
        Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

Thank you very much for your time and consideration.